# Possible to port gui functions with swig

Tags: gtk, swig, go

I was wondering if it would be possible to port the gtk gui framework to Go with the swig wrapper? Or am I just living in a fantasy world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, yes. It looks like SWIG support for Go is limited right now.

The real problem with simple SWIG wrappers is the ugly details leak through. The produced interface would need a layer on top of it in order to provide "Goish" behavior, especially in regards to garbage collection and interfaces.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I had seen some other people port a library that contained a window function, so I thought that seeing as how you can port that window function, then maybe you could port an entire gui framework.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. SWIG isn't even strictly necessary, but it does make the process more automatic.

There's already a GTK binding for Go in progress here:
http://github.com/mattn/go-gtk